# best way to show several images on a winform in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, image

best way to show several images on a winform in c#?  Datagrid?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: What look are you going for? How many images? Does the number of images change dynamically?

Comment: I would like to see a single row of images all next to each other (vertical or horizontal) that the user can scroll throw.  This is for a photo search or to display all photo assigned to a user.  I am guess from 0 to 1000 images. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

Several `PictureBox`es :-)

Comment: Maybe I could get a blank panel control and add picture boxes to the panel control dynamically.  Then I could make the panel control scrollable. I guess it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Left a treeview with all the images and mainform the image large? It's kinda hard to guess what you want...

Comment: I didn't know that a tree view could display images without the images being in a imagelist.  I will check it out.  thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

My company, Atalasoft, has several [win forms controls](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/photopro/default.aspx) that can be used for displaying images and thumbnails.
There is a typical example of using the thumbnail control [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/TIFF_editing.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many images you want to display, do you want thumbnails or full-resolution images?

I'm going to assume that since you asked for "images", you have many images to display. As such, you'll probably be wanting to use thumbnails on that form, with a different form if you want to display the full-resolution image.

In this case, you'll want to look at the ImageList object in conjunction with the ListView object.

I used this solution in an app recently. It worked out very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an ImageList and binding it to a ListView. You can set the ListView to Tile View state or any other states.